# ConTeXt: Increment user page number for TEX page

Tags: page-numbering, context-lmtx

## Background

A few different start/stop environments insert a TEX page.

ConTeXt Version: 2023.07.18 22:07

## Problem

The TEX page doesn't increment the user page number.

## Code

For example:

```
\definestartstop[corrupted][
  before={
    \startTEXpage[
      offset=\backspace,
      width=\paperwidth,
      height=\paperheight
    ]%
    \incrementnumber[userpage]
  },
  after={\stopTEXpage},
]

\definestartstop[banned][
  before={%
    \startTEXpage[
      align=middle,
      offset=\backspace,
      width=\paperwidth,
      height=\paperheight,
    ]%
    \incrementnumber[userpage]
  },
  after={\stopTEXpage},
]
```

## XY Problem

The deeper issue is inserting pages without headers/footers. TEX pages provide full control over the layout, including easily changing the page background before inserting the TEX page:

```
\setupbackgrounds[page][%
  background=color,
  backgroundcolor=TextColourBannedPage,
]
\startTEXpage[
  % etc.
```

## Question

Is there something like `\setupTEXpage` where the "inherited" behaviour is to increment the user page number? Such as:

```
\setupTEXpage[runnerless][
  before={\incrementnumber[userpage]},
  offset=\backspace,
  width=\paperwidth,
  height=\paperheight
]
```

Possibly `\setupfittingpage`?

I'm not sure if defining a macro would help because the two TEX pages have different alignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\setupTEXpage[pagestate=start]` should do what you want:

```tex
\setupTEXpage[pagestate=start]

\starttext
\dorecurse{100}{
    \startTEXpage
        \getnumber[userpage]
    \stopTEXpage
}
\stoptext
```

> The deeper issue is inserting pages without headers/footers. TEX pages provide full control over the layout, including easily changing the page background before inserting the TEX page

That's not really the intended use for fitting (“TEX”) pages. You probably want `\definemakeup` (wiki [1](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup), [2](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Makeup), [3](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Standardmakeup_background)) instead.